# Showing Wait Cursor on TextChanged Event Of TextBox

Tags: asp.net

I want to show a wait cursor on Text Changed event till the data is fetched from the server.
And then reset the cursor to default.

Should work in ie6.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET is a server-side technology which will not allow you to actually act on the browser.

Assuming there was no postback—you're using ajax, for example—you can achieve the desired behaviour with some JavaScript and CSS (with the `cursor` property).

If there was a postback and you are simply waiting for the server to load a new page, there is nothing that you can do.